# Rails .includes not returning association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, include, associations

I have the following setup:
Company has_many :locations
Location belongs_to :company

When I call Company.includes(:locations), I'm getting the company returned back, but none of the associated locations.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: If you're just fetching a single company and want to load it's locations, you don't need to use `includes`. Doing @company = Company.find(params[:id])` followed by `@company.locations` will perform just as many queries as `@company = Company.includes(:locations).find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eager Loading is necessary as it optimizes the performance of your application and prevent your system to run into N+1 query problem. Suppose you have 3000 companies in your database then your database will be flooded with 3000+1 queries. So in the controller you can achieve it as

```
@companies = Company.includes(:locations)
```

Similarly for single company you can do it as

```
@company = Company.includes(:locations).find(params[:id])
```

Now locations will be eagerly loaded and you can fetch them as

```
@companies.collect{ |company| company.locations }
```

OR

```
@company.locations
```

> Note you can use any iterator. I used 'collect' just for the purpose of elaboration. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with a company, but if you want one company and it's locations you would generally do the following:

```
class Company
   has_many :locations
end

class Location
  belongs_to :company
end

class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    @locations = @company.locations
  end
end
```

Then in your `show` view, you would call `@locations.each do |location|` in order to iterate over the list of `locations`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem when trying to send the data from my query back as JSON.

`@companies = Company.includes(:locations)
render :json => @companies.to_json( :include => [:locations] )`

Worked for me :)